# How can I create my custom properties on xml for Android?

Tags: java, android

We have in our project a keyboard with "Key" elements, this Key elements have attributes such as android:codes="119", android:keyLabel="w" and so on.

My question is how can I include an custom attribute like a "android:alternativeKeyLabel" to do something else.

Answer (score 59):

This link gives a superficial explanation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Considering you have a CustomKeyboard that inherits from KeyboardView/View:

1. Create your custom properties in res/values/attrs.xml file (create the file if it does not exist):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>    <declare-styleable name="custom_keyboard">
>         <attr name="alternative_key_label" format="string" />
>     </declare-styleable>
>
> </resources>
> ```

1. Create a constructor in your custom component overriding default constructor that receives the attribute set because this one will be called when the layout is loaded.

   ```
   public CustomKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
       super(context, set);
       TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(set,R.styleable.custom_keyboard);
       CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.custom_keyboard_alternative_key_label);
       if (s != null) {
           this.setAlternativeKeyLabel(s.toString());
       }
       a.recycle();
   }
   ```
2. In your layout file, add your custom component and the link to your resources.

> ```
>  <Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package.ProjectName"
>     .../>
>     ...
>     <your.package.projectname.CustomKeyboard
>         android:id="@+id/my_keyboard"
>         ...
>         app:alternative_key_label="F">
>     </your.package.projectname.CustomKeyboard>
> </Layout>
> ```

Comment: When trying to use custom views with custom attributes from libraries (e.g. Customizing the Facebook Login Button), layouts using custom attributes must use the namespace URI "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" instead of the URI that includes the app package name. This URI is replaced with the app specific one at build time.
That is, "xmlns:app..." should be replaced with:
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
And, when using, "app:custom_property..." with:
"custom:custom_property..."

Obs.: only ADT revision 17+ added support for this.

Comment: To future readers: Be careful to read the complete last code example. The `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package.ProjectName` line in the top level element is required to be able to access the app namespace.

Comment: according to @JPMagalhaes info: xmlns:custom="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto worked for me. thank you!

Comment: @JPMagalhaes you're a genius. Simple and straight forward. I only had to add the line `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, **in addition to** `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`, then I could add attributes from a library I'm using, such as `custom:pstsUnderlineColor="#ffffff"` in my custom widget. Thanks so much!

Comment: How can we listen the change of these xml attributes in edit mode (design time). The constructor of the view will not be called again for attribute change in xml file.

Comment: What @JPMagalheas said  about writing custom:mycustomattr instead of android:miscustomattr and add xmlns:custom="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" is  true also when we don't use libraries but only simple android component.

Comment: @JPMagalhaes , is it necessary to override the constructor or is it only for the keyboard example?

Comment: It is always necessary since it receives the attribute set that will be called when the layout is loaded. Without it you are not able to get the value set in your xml file.

Answer (score 11):

For any other purpose, declaring a custom property in the XML file can be retrieve with attrs constructor parameter.

In my case I reuse a preference custom dialog, and set things like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- something here -->
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <your.package.projectname.CustomView
        foo="bar"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then in my class contructor:

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    String bar = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "foo");
    Log.d("CustomView", "foo=" + bar);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create custom attributes for your own classes that extend View or a subclass. The process is documented in the "Creating a View Class" section of the Android Dev Guide under the heading "Define Custom Attributes":

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr

Comment: All 3 links are dead :( This answer is not help.

Comment: Not my fault Google changed their site compared to 9 years ago when that was written. :) Here's a modern link to Google's docs on making custom view properties:https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr

Answer (score 0):

android:keyLabel is one of many XML attribute used by the Keyboard.Key class for each key on your keyboard.  android:keyLabel is what you want to label the key with (like a "w" as in above).  The attributes are pre-defined for the class.  The "w" isn't but android:keyLabel is.   If you could create android:alternativeKeyLabel what would you expect the class to do with it?  I think maybe you should try to explain further what you are trying to accomplish.