# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth for Android

Tags: android, textview

The iPhone has the method adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth for the UILabel.

Is there a way to automatically adjust the width of the text to match the width TextView or Button in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard of any direct methods in Android which can do this for you. This post has a class customized for the same purpose. Did you check this out??

[How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266)