# android full screen textview

Tags: android, textview, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview)

I am trying to create an app that has a simple textview displaying a count down. All the menus and such will be hidden under a long press or with the menu button.

I'm trying to find away to make the text in that text view automatically scale and take up the whole screen something like android:textSize="100%"

Despite lots of search I can't seem to find an easy way to do this