# Display portion of Text on Webview such that WebView fits the screen size [doesnt scroll]

Tags: android, webview

m developing an ebook reader application.

i wanna display text in `WebView` [have to use `WebView` instead of `TextView` bcz `TextView` doesnt support `justify text align`]

Now how will i know how much text i shud display on 1 page , so that the `WebView` doesnt `scroll`?

`WebView:getContentHeight()` is not working..
i need to get the height of the `html content` b4 i `loaddata` in the `WebView`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the scroll of webview using the following code.

```
WebView appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.appView); 
appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: hi deepak, yr code just disables the scrollbars visibility, the view still scrolls. What i want is "How much portion of the text shud i display so that it fits the WebView size & doesnt scroll"

Comment: Can you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview