# Android: Adjusting EditText font size to fit text to one line

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, font-size

I am making an app that has two `EditText` views, `txtOne` which is used for input, and `txtTwo` which is used for output. `txtOne` is editable, and `txtTwo` is not.

I am looking for a simple way to `scale the font size of the text` in these two views so that it always fits within the view without wrapping to a new line.

I have found a few implementations of this using custom views extending `TextView`, but they aren't fit for an `EditText` view, or use `android.graphics.Paint`, which is not what I am looking for.

Is there any way to check to see when text in an `EditText` view is wrapping? If so, then it would be easy enough to do something like:

```
if(txtOne.isWrappingText()) {
    txtOne.setTextSize(txtOne.getTextSize() - 2);
}
```

Does anyone know of any way to detect this or an alternative solution?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7875656/435605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I deleted my post**

Basically the suggested code contained a `TextWatcher` for the `EditText`, this helped to answer the question. But the code itself was just wrong (I tested it meanwhile).

I suggest to read [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds) because they adress the very same issue...

Comment: +1 for TextWatcher -- I forgot that you can use the beforeTextChanged event in a TExtWatcher, where you can't when making a custom EditText view. This specific example, however, just makes the font size very-very small from the start. I feel like something in my code is causing the text changed event to fire multiple times, but that's another issue in my case: I do a lot of subtle changes to the text content, so that's bound to happen. Still looking for different solutions

Comment: I'm so dump ;-) I think you ment [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview/3378422#3378422) in your question. My idea matches that one exactly (even the improvement by a binary search ;-), but he has provided a complete implementation. Have you tried to use that and simply extend an `EditText` instead of a `TextView` (since `EditText` extends `TextView` anyways).

Comment: I found that post a little earlier, and I was looking at it. I think I've found a solution for my very specific case (nothing general i could share). I have a lot of handlers set up already, and so I basically did some calculations in those to adjust the font size.