# Custom (extended) textview in textswitcher

Tags: android, textview

Ok so I'm trying to use the custom textview from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875656/938541

Now I need to have a textswitcher (would viewswitcher be a better choice) to switch between 2 textviews (custom textviews in this case) while always writing new text.

When adding a view to the textswitcher this worked for me so far:

```
new TextView();
```

I tried something like this for the custom textview:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.customtxtview);
```

With a xml file:

```
<com.seelenkalender.FontFitTextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This setup and other similar approaches that I tried forceclose...

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add id not layout is Eg. `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stringA);`