# Self-adjusting text size depending on the available room

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Im trying to do the following:

Given a max dimensions (for example 400x400). Make a text whose size varies to fill the space. For example if the desired text is "A" it will have a high textSize value, but if I put a long sentence its textSize should be reduced in order to fit the size.

Is possible to implement that easily? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your level of experience. "Easily" is subjective. There are [implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview) out there that provide decent starting places.

Answer (score 1):

```
Give the textview fill_parent hight and width so that as you type e.g ASDF then it will automatically reduce size and if only "A" then it will show max hight and widht.
This textview will set in layout which hight and width you will set as you want like 400*400.
If any double catch me..
```

Best
V.k