# Android: String fill text box

Tags: android, layout

I don't really know where to look as I'm starting out with Android.

How would I automatically make a String assigned to a Button in Android, take on an appropriate font size according to the button's size?

Answer (score 0):

extend class Button, override `onMeasure` method and there you can compute view's height and set proper text size

Comment: How do I get the parrent's size then?

Comment: check this question, this mai help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview