# A Simple Misunderstanding: How can I incorporate java class on Android

Tags: java, android

this maybe the simpliest question therein, but please be considerate for me.

I am researching some tutorial/s regarding how to wrap text inside a EditText and I think these links will help me a lot.

[StackOverFlow Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672)

[StackOverFlow Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview/7875656#7875656)

Now my question is, how can I incorporate that java class. As you see I am still a student and I have little experience on these **extends**. 
I've tried using instantiate (I am more prone on vb.net) and here is my code

```
private AutoResizeTextView autoResizeTextView;// instantiate

//and on my textview
txtCalc.setTextSize(autoResizeTextView);
```

it isnt working. Can you help me fix my declaration cause I am trying to create a calculator for my school project?

Thanks a lot for your time and effort

**EDIT**
I dont know if I understand it correctly but this what I do on my layout

```
    <com.bracks.androidtest.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_border"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:textSize="30dp" 
    />
```

Sir it isnt working. I dont know if that is because of the code

Comment: It will be **much** better for you if you'll read any java book first (at least first 100-200 pages). We can explain you where is your mistakes, but it won't help you a lot.

Comment: Do you need just show autoresize text view or something else? Are You really trying to 'extend' it in java terms?

Comment: @biovamp I am grateful that you answer my question, but I got a huge problem. I am passing it tommorrow and I dont have enough time if I will search on the book. Thats why I am seeking for professional help (I dont mean to be rude)

Comment: @sandrstar what I am trying to do is use those tutorial and incorporate it on my textview cause my textview is not wrapping and I dont want it to be scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you'll understand it:

First of all:

```
private AutoResizeTextView autoResizeTextView;// instantiate
```

you're not instantinated anything there. To create object you must call the constructor.

```
//and on my textview
txtCalc.setTextSize(autoResizeTextView);
```

Looks like your `txtCalc` should be `AutoResizeTextView` instead of `TextView`. **Do not try this**:

```
txtCalc = autoResizeTextView;
```

Instead change view type in your XML file (layout) from `<TextView />` to `<yourPackageName.AutoResizeTextView></yourPackageName.AutoResizeTextView>`