# Cannot set Font size as TextView's height

Tags: android, textview, android-canvas

In my app I set one TextView and I noticed that there were some spaces above and below the text, as in the image below.

[image]

But my expected result is this :-

[image]

I Googled lots and found this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2617266/1367157), but nothing happens.

**Updated :**

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="50dp"
              android:background="#484848"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              android:text="A"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

This is the tag I used for displaying text.

Updated :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="50dp"
              android:background="#484848"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              android:text="A"
              android:paddingTop="0dp"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Updated Image :**

[image]

Comment: Hey add your TextView tag code i.e., xml layout code. it is hard to say what mistake you are doing without checking code.

Comment: Whats for Parent Layout for this TextView?

Comment: @ChronicallyInsane. i did that but nothing ..... :(

Comment: @user370305 i set RelativeLayout as Parent .

Comment: did that but it fill whole height of relativeLayout.

Comment: No other views only one textview. I gave you my whole layout code.

Comment: Just copy this code in your eclipse and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, its a padding of **9-patch backgrounds drawable** which is by default for Android TextView background. And you are just set color to it `#484848`. So you don't have any solution for it.

As per my concern use the same size of `height (android:layout_height)` for your TextView  as same as your `TextSize (android:textSize="50dip")` of your TextView. `(instead of android:layout_height="wrap_content")`

Try with below code:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="50dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
              android:textSize="50dip"
              android:background="#484848"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              android:text="A"
              android:includeFontPadding="false"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

I also added some margin in negative.  `android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"`

Hope this will help you a little bit.

Comment: see my result picture and please let me know that can we make it perfect ??

Comment: @xDeveloper - You can use `android:layout_marginTop` or `android:paddingTop`.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` only works at certain times, for example, when you `setHeight(), setWidth(), setText(), setMinHeight(), ...`. These methods will request the layout to wrap the content again.

But `setTextSize()` doesn't request the layout.

To trigger `wrap_content` to work again, you can call `setMinHeight(0)`.