# Android Auto Font Resizer

Tags: android

I am working on Android textview,case is i have a specific height of textview,i want to adjust the text in the given textview height by adjusting the font size.If a text is of 10 charachers it will covers the whole height and if text is off 400 characters it will decreases the font to adjust in height of textview. I have tried auto text resize class but it does not getting the desire result.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for FontFit TextView. [Check out here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875656/2345913)

You just have to use it instaed of normal `TextView` like this..

```
TextView tv = new FontFitTextView(context);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own logic for that like

1- : Count no or character in side text watcher

2- : if no of character more then 10 then reduce the size of test using textsize method.

3- : the same logic if character more then 10 then reduce the size of test using textsize method.

or you can also put it on loop then i think you can achieve it also.