# Textview: adjust font size to match parent

Tags: android, user-interface

Is it possible to set **font size** to automatically `match_parent`?

My `TextView` is already `width/height="match_parent"` but the font size is small and doesn't fit to the parent size.

How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3378422/1239966

Comment: The problem is it takes into account only the `width` of the parent.

Answer (score 13):

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

add this line to your `TextView`

**Edit**:
this line will work for api 26 and higher so if you want to use it for api lower than 26 use this

```
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

if adding this line gives you error ignore the error by adding

```
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
```