# Android - NullPointerException in my textView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

i want to change a text of my text view to fill the parent.
i'm following this question: [How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview?rq=1)

But i have a nullPointerException when i try to manage my FontFitTextView istance.

this is my java code:

```
     @SuppressLint("WrongCall") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_avatar);

    LinearLayout llyCoins = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llyCoins);

    FontFitTextView textCoins = new FontFitTextView(this);
    textCoins.onMeasure( llyCoins.getMeasuredWidth(),llyCoins.getMeasuredHeight());

    Log.d("FLAG", "error in this line");
    // rimuovo il parent da textcoins
    ((ViewGroup)textCoins.getParent()).removeView(textCoins);


   // aggiungo textcoins alla view llycoins
    llyCoins.addView(textCoins);
```

i have a null pointer exception in this line :

```
 ((ViewGroup)textCoins.getParent()).removeView(textCoins);
```

my xml:

```
 <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/llyCoins"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: TextCoins isnt added to a view. So when you try tl remove it, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add your text view to linear layout then you can use getParent

```
LinearLayout llyCoins = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llyCoins);

FontFitTextView textCoins = new FontFitTextView(this);

llyCoins.addView(textCoins);    

textCoins.onMeasure( llyCoins.getMeasuredWidth(),llyCoins.getMeasuredHeight());

Log.d("FLAG", "error in this line");
// rimuovo il parent da textcoins
((ViewGroup)textCoins.getParent()).removeView(textCoins);


// aggiungo textcoins alla view llycoins
llyCoins.addView(textCoins);
```

Comment: i remove the removeView, because is not useful. my problem was that i have two addView , and i had not noticed it..

Comment: I just copied your own code and added the missing line! ;)

Comment: yes but i had another addView outside my pasted code