# Fit the text size in textview

Tags: android

I have a function that generates a random number. Then, I place the number in a `TextView`. When the number is a single digit, it fills the `TextView` perfectly, but when the number is two digits or more, it only shows a single digit because the text size is huge.

How do I automatically fit the text size to the `TextView`? Something like reduce the text size so that all the number will be shown in the `TextView`.

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Comment: post your textview code.

Comment: See here, this probably pertains to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview

Comment: First post your code of TextView that what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I must abuse an answer. No need to reduce the number's size. Just make sure the TextView is set to wrap_context in the layout:width property and also possibly the layout:height property, that should fix your formatting problem.