# Readjust text inside an EditText (android)

Tags: java, android, text, android-edittext, bounds

Is possible to change dynamically the size of the text of an EditText when the text is too long and readjust it to fit within the bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should create a custom TextView. Check out @speedplane soulution :
 [How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875656/5079879)

Comment: It is something like I want to do... but I want to resize the text inside the editText,  not a text View

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (editText.getText().toString().length() > 15)
        {
            editText.setTextSize(10)
        }
});
```

I've not tested this but that should generally work.

Comment: But in some devices (with a bigger screen), the editText can containsmore than 15 chars..... instead, smaller screen devices can contain less than 15 chars