# Android : how to detect language has been changes on phone setting

Tags: android, locale

how could i detect if my phone language has been changed, like facebook application that will give us announce : `please wait, we preparing your language`

i used `myString = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`in my `onCreate()`

on my `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String myString = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        if(myString.equals("en"){
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, we preparing your language");
            progressDialog.show();
            /*
            it will dismiss until the language has been prepared
             */
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

please give me suggestion, i still learning, will try harder. thank you.

Answer (score 14):

You can use: [ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED)

Here an example:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mLangReceiver = null;

    protected BroadcastReceiver setupLangReceiver(){

        if(mLangReceiver == null) {

            mLangReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // do what you want
                }

            };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mLangReceiver, filter);
        }

        return mLangReceiver;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

What about to make a broadcast listener to: ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

Since "Locale represents a language/country/variant combination. Locales are used to alter the presentation of information such as numbers or dates to suit the conventions in the region they describe."

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: i have opened it, but i don't understand how to implement on my program.

Answer (score 2):

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

You can use this to get languages in "en"-like format.

`Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();` returns language name e.g. "English" not "en".

This is also useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265899/5515972

Comment: if i use progressDialog as notification if the language has been changes, so when the progressBar dismiss, (case : doesn't use timer )

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Your answer gets the current locale. It doesn't detect when the locale has changed.

Comment: When getting the locale you should use `Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales[0]` instead of `Locale.getDefault()`. Reference: https://medium.com/@hectorricardomendez/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-android-fc12d8be6242

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more modern way to get locale changes using `Flow`. Like others mentioned, we'll need a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the `Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED` action. To start, add this function to create the `Flow`.

```
private fun getLocaleChangedFlow(context: Context) = callbackFlow {
    val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED) {
                val locale = context?.resources?.configuration?.locales?.get(0)
                if (locale != null) {
                    trySend(locale)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED))

    awaitClose {
        context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }
}
```

Then use the `Flow`. Replace the `TODO()` with your own logic:

```
getLocaleChangedFlow(context)
    .onEach {
        TODO() // Locale changed, add code here
    }
    .launchIn(coroutineScope)
```

To learn more, see these links:

[Kotlin docs about callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html)

[Android docs for Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED)

[StackOverflow answer to Wrap a BroadcastReceiver in a Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67113600/3422470)