# Wrap Broadcast receiver into Flow (coroutine)

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, kotlin-coroutines, android-wifi

I have a broadcast receiver for wifi scan results as a data source and I'd like to make it in coroutine way. I found an answer for suspend function here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520496/5938671

```
suspend fun getCurrentScanResult(): List<ScanResult> =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        //define broadcast reciever
        val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(c: Context, intent: Intent) {
                if (intent.action?.equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) == true) {
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                    cont.resume(wifiManager.scanResults)
                }
            }
        }
        //setup cancellation action on the continuation
        cont.invokeOnCancellation {
            context.unregisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver)
        }
        //register broadcast reciever
        context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
        //kick off scanning to eventually receive the broadcast
        wifiManager.startScan()
    }
```

This is fine for signle emit, but if I want to get results while scanning is going then I'll get crash because `cont.resume()` could be called only once. Then I decided to try `Flow`. And here is my code:

```
suspend fun getCurrentScanResult(): Flow<List<ScanResult>> =
    flow{
        val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(c: Context, intent: Intent) {
                if (intent.action?.equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) == true) {
                    //context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                    emit(wifiManager.scanResults)
                }
            }
        }
        //setup cancellation action on the continuation
        //register broadcast reciever
        context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
        //kick off scanning to eventually receive the broadcast
        wifiManager.startScan()
    }
```

But now Android Stuidio says `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` for function `emit(wifiManager.scanResults)` Is there a way to use Flow here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please take a look at the [callback flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) which is specifically designed for this use case. Something like this will do the job:

```
callbackFlow {
  val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
      if (intent.action == WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) {
        sendBlocking(wifiManager.scanResults) // or non-blocking offer()
      }
    }
  } 
  context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)

  awaitClose {
      context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
  }
}
```

You also might want to share this flow with e.g. [shareIn](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html) operator to avoid registering a new receiver for each flow subscriber.

Comment: its experimental api

Comment: @RichaShah it's no longer experimental