# Android when my text exceeded the width horizontal programatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to know how I can get the condition in the onclick, my edittext is a singleline and I want to know when the text is exceeded, for example my edittext has 6 characters "HOLAHI" I add a new character and this show "HOL...".

I want to know until to set the 7th character to change the size font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: [How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview)

Overview:

- Create a CustomTextView
- Extend TextView
- override method onMeasure()
- Do your calculations on the text width [Hint: get width by calling this.getWidth()]
- Set calculated text size [Hint: use this.setTextSize()]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content of your `EditText` should ellipsize by the method provided in `TextUtils`, the following code is a simple example.

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String ellipseString = TextUtils.ellipsize(s, editText.getPaint(), editText.getWidth(), TextUtils.TruncateAt.END, false, new TextUtils.EllipsizeCallback() {
                @Override
                public void ellipsized(int start, int end) {
                }
            }).toString();
            if (ellipseString.contains("\u2026")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ellipse");
            }
        }
    });
```