# TextView text height fit to screen size and auto resize width as fit to screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, font-size, word-wrap

I want to fit my `TextView` text height as my phone full screen height and text width auto resize as my phone screen width size.
I check the all the possible solution of this two question

1. [How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview/)
2. [Auto Scale Text View Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672)

but for me this all return my text with resize and decreases the text height. 
i spend lot of time for this but all but no one stack overflow solution answer to get full height with resize width.
if you know how to do this please help me with this.
*this images are made in photo shop for example*

i want like example below
[image: one text]  [image: two text]  [image: three text]

Comment: is anyone know how to solve this issue ?