# How to update constraints after scale a view in Android ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, constraints

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**
I just used setTextScaleX instead of setScalex to scale the textView and it worked as what I expected this time.

Just like the photos above.
I use ConstraintLayout to keep the space between "$" and center textView and "00". 
When I set 5555 to the center textView, it became wider, but I want to keep its original size.
So I scaled the "5555" part, I found the constraints did not update as well.
Can anybody give me some advice?
Thanks a lot!

My layout xml is as following.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.echo.tipcalculator.fragments.FeeUnitFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_title"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_unit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fee_title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/fee_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fee_unit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fee_unit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_decimal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fee_main"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fee_main"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml so we can play with it?

Comment: Just updated my post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the xml, I see it looking like the top example you posted.  What do you mean when you say you're trying to scale it?  What is it you change that makes the 55 get thinner?

Comment: Updated my post again. Hope you can understand my problems now. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you trying to scale the text size within the bounds of the existing text field?  (As the numbers get larger, the height and width of each number becomes smaller to allow the entire number to fit in the field)  If that's the case, there are some other posts about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview  Also, there's a github project that's not a library, but the author encourages you to copy and paste his custom text view into your own project: https://github.com/erchenger/SizeAdjustingTextView/blob/master/SizeAdjustingTextView.java

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used setTextScaleX and solved my problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144399/discussion-between-themichaelscott-and-echo).