# auto-fit TextView and spannableString

Tags: android, textview, font-size, spannablestring

**background**

i need to show amount of money in textView with SpannableString and then fit the font of the TextView to the boundaries given to it, as follows:

[image]

**SpannableString Code:**

```
String s= "2,000,000.000";
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);

ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.4f), 0,1, 0); // set size 2
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 2,5, 0); // set size 000 (first)
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 6,9, 0); // set size 000 (second)
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1f), 10,13, 0); // set size 000 (Third)

TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.money);
tv.setText(ss1);
```

**The problem**

My problem is to fit the text size with screen width

I tried to use the solutions for these posts([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)) but none of them not work well with SpannableString.

**The question**

Does anybody know of a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i solved this problem myself

**Along with enlarging, I used miniaturize**

like this:

```
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f),  0,  1,  0);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan( 1f ),  2,  5,  0);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan( 1f ),  6,  9,  0);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f),  10, 13, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

چطوری پسر؟
You can get both Width and Height of the Screen and Use it Everywhere:

```js
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
final int DisplayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
final int DisplayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

And in Your Case you want to set width for `tv` like Below:

```
tv.getLayoutParams().width = DisplayWidth;
```

This Measurement is Very powerful, Feel free to use it everywhere. The ONLY thing to Consider For HEIGHT, If you have your Activity Flag on FULL_SCREEN You Actually Need to Consider Navigation Bar Height As well Which is in most Smartphones 48dp

This means you can Use `DisplayHeight+ContextCompat.getDimen(mContext,R.dimen.dimen48);`

And define dimen48 in your dimen.xml as 48dp

Comment: jigar too xml Vaseye Toole Font 'wrap_content' ro Tanzim Kardi?? Age Nasho begoo Vasat Inja ye Code Benevisam

Comment: Ok, Daram Vasat Minevisam

Comment: اومد. ببین جواب میده؟

Comment: ببینم میخوای طول تنظیم بشه، یا سایز فونت؟ میگی سایز فونت تغییر نمیکنه؟

Comment: Khob spannableString az API21 Lollipop be Bala Kar mikone, va yek bar ham ba in tanzimat check kon: android:textAllCaps="false",  "android:mutileLine", android:ellipsize="end",  and android:singleLine="false;

Comment: Emtehaaan Kon. Alan bokon begoooo chi shoood

Comment: ای بابا. حالا در میارم واست اگه نتونستی. اما فعلاً باید برم سعید جان. ببخش جواب نگرفتی. دوس داشتی بهم پیام بده.  ۰۹۳۸۸۵۲۸۷۲۹

Comment: Ghorboonet mamnunam. Nice to meet you too. Contact me whenever you want ;*

Answer (score -1):

First, This is How you can Set Width and Height for your Textview:

1. If your TextView is Inside a RelativeLayour:

```js
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();

params.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.any_width_you_want);
params.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.any_height_you_want);

tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

2. If your TextView is inside anything else:

```js
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();

params.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.any_width_you_want);
params.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.any_height_you_want);

tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

3. Now, Your `tv` TextView has a Text Size which you defined in xml source right? Let's say your TextView Font size is 14sp.

Tha means your TextView Height is 14+6 -- > 20dp

So, See what Font Size is your `tv` Textview

4. I Assume your textview size is 14sp. Now you Need to Calculate the Highest Scale in SpannableString you Created.

Based on `ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.4f), 0,1, 0);` Highest Scale is `1.4f`

This means Your highest HEIGHT for `tv` is (20dp)*1.4

SO The Final Height You Want is <<<28dp>>>

5. Define this 28dp in your `dimens.xml` like this:

```js
<< ? xml version = "1.0"encoding = "utf-8" ? >
  <resources >
  ...
 
  <dimen name ="dimen28">28dp< /dimen>  
 
  ... 
  
 
  </resources>
```

6. Now you're Done by Doing This:

```js
params.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dimen28);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

یادت نره من فرض کردم سایز فونت شما 14 هستش.
این کار رو با سایز فونت خودت انجام بده