# Does Android studio layout editor shows custom view properties?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have a compound view which consists of two Buttons and one Text view. I want to edit properties of these child views in the Android Studio Layout Editor but I can't. It only shows basic properties but no properties of my custom view.

Does the Android Studio Layout Editor only shows limited number of properties set by default? Is it possible to edit properties of my custom view from there, without manually editing the XML files?

[image: Custom View]

[image: Properties panel not showing custom view properties]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Maybe this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029719/how-can-i-create-my-custom-properties-on-xml-for-android

Comment: @SteffenTimm: It doesn't explain, how to show custom properties in Layout Editor panel

Answer (score 2):

As described in http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr you have to add a new ressource (res/values/attrs.xml).

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Within your View you have to reference this new ressource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
     <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart
         custom:showText="true"
         custom:labelPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you should see the properties in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but unfortunately the custom properties are not shown up in the android studio design panel. Does it working for you?

Comment: At the moment I didn't develop for Android but I think it worked this way in the past

Comment: Unfortunatelly Android Studio can't showing the custom attributes in design panel

Comment: This code does work in the editor of Android Studio 1.5+ as long as you change it to use the standard "app"  namespace: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` (instead of the `xmlns:custom`) at the top of the XML and `app:showText` and `app:labelPosition` in the view definition. However the special `tools:` override namespace for editor-only (not runtime) values does not work currently. (All this also depends on the custom view constructor code implementing and loading those XML attribute values from `context.obtainStyledAttributes` as mentioned in the referenced docs.)

Comment: See this example https://gist.github.com/jon-adams/968a3a7325cae9502873 that adds this kind of support to Volley's NetworkImageView which didn't load its custom properties from XML -- now it does with this custom view.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
xmlns:sidespinner="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to

```
xmlns:sidespinner="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

android studio will show custom attributes of your custom view.

be sure you defined custom attributes in `res/values/attrs.xml`

Answer (score 0):

If you customize a `View` with custom attributes, you need to use your own **namespace** to set your custom attributes.

**First**, set namespace in the root view of your layout like this:

```
xmlns:sidespinner="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Since custom attribute names are declared in your `res/values/attrs.xml` of your current project or library project, **namespace `sidespinner`** will tell `aapt` to obtain attributes from your current project or library project.

**Second**, set custom attributes in your custom `View` like this:

```
<your-custom-view
     sidespinner:boolean-attr="true"
     sidespinner:integer-attr="5"
     sidespinner:enum-attr="none"//your enum values
     sidespinner:dimen-attr="10dp" />
```

I hope you are clear about this. If you want to know how to customize attributes, refer to @SteffenTimm's answer.