# Android Studio Designer Pannel doesn't show any custom properties of a view/custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying for last 3 days to show up my custom view properties in my Android Studio Design Panel, so I can directly edit custom properties of my view directly from the design editor and my supervisor can create an app without any coding knowledge by dragging a view in editor and simply editing its properties from the designer panel.(without modifying XML code. It is a very simple app, so I think its just okay).

However, it seems I have no luck. I have asked one question on it, got only one reply and its also not working. The question is here:

[Does Android studio layout editor shows custom view properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072453/does-android-studio-layout-editor-shows-custom-view-properties)

I have checked almost all custom properties of views in android tutorials, downloaded source codes and find that none of these was able to show up the custom properties in android design panel.

So now, I have big doubt, if it is actually possible to show up any custom properties for a view in Android Studio. Its a bit strange that there is no single discussion/tutorial on it in online. Every tutorial suggests, how to create custom properties using xml layout or code, but none discussed, how to show up that in android studio. I believe, andoid studio can only show up default properties set for a view and we have to edit custom properties by editing XML files only.

Can you please tell me if its correct? I am really very frustrated with it and want to leave it now. If any of you got succeed to bring custom properties of views in Android Studio editor, I will be very grateful, if you kindly reply/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the below API level than current in that designer panel.